# I am Using Zxing LIbrary in my Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, zxing

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        self.capture = nil;
        self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
        self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;
        self.capture.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;
        self.capture.rotation = 90.0f;

        self.capture.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.frame.size.width,            self.view.frame.size.height);
        self.capture.delegate = self;
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];
        [self.capture start];
    }
```

I am stopped the camera, i am using the below method its works fine

```
[self.capture stop];
```

I am trying to start the camera , i am using the below method

```
[self.capture start];
```

the above method is not working unable open the camera for scanning

Please help 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you allocating it multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of stop method has

```
[self.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

The layer is removed from self.view.layer, so in your start method, add the layer again and bring your custom views to front.

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.startButton];
[self.capture start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use ZXing, iOS7 supports barcode scanning (http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx)

Comment: Is it able to scan all driver license in PDF417 format? I tested it on one license, it worked great.

Comment: Yes it is, and you dont need to import a library and it is directly supported by apple.

Answer (score 0):

Please move the start method viewDidAppear it works fine for me.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        [self.capture start];
    }
```